# Python: No value for argument 'filenames' in unbound method call

Tags: python

I have a class to wrap around the config stuff of my program.
But when I try to test i in ipython like this:

```
c = Config(test.cfg)
```

I get the error:

```
"TypeError: read() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filenames'
"
```

But I pylint throws this error in my emacs:

```
"No value for argument 'filenames' in unbound method call"
```

I think the error adbove is the reason of the error above it.
But I don't know why.
I think the method is call bound since I used self as reference but I'm not shure and I don't get why it doesn't accept cfg as paramter.

This is my class:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

class Config:
    """Wrapper around config files
    Args:
        cfg: main config file
    """
    def __init__(self, cfg=None):
        self.cfg = []
        self.cfgraw = cfg
        self.scfgs = []
        self.scfgs_raw = []
        if not cfg is None:
            self.add(typ="main", cfg=cfg)


    def add(self, typ, cfg):
        """add config file
        Args:
             typ: type of file main or sub
        Returns:
             none
        """
        if typ is not "main" and cfg is None:
            raise ValueError('no file provied and type not main')

        if typ is "sub":
            for index in range(len(self.scfgs)):
                self.scfgs[index] = ConfigParser
                self.scfgs[index].read(cfg)

        if typ is "main":
            self.cfg = ConfigParser
            self.cfg.read(cfg)
    def write(self, typ=None, index=None):
        """write changes made
        Args:
            typ: type of target file
            index: if type is sub add index to write selected file
        Returns:
            none
        """
        if typ is "main":
            self.cfg.write(self.cfgraw)
        if typ is "sub":
            if index is None:
                for item in range(len(self.scfgs)):
                    self.scfgs[item].write(self.scfgs_raw[item])
            else:
                self.scfgs[item].write(self.scfgs_raw[item])
```

Answer (score 18):

You are not initializing your `ConfigParser` correctly on the line before the `read` -- you are missing the `()` to actually create an instance.

Try:

```
if typ is "main":
    self.cfg = ConfigParser()
    self.cfg.read(cfg)
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't instantiate `ConfigParser` when you assign it to the `self.scfgs` or `self.cfg` attributes; so when you then call `read` on it, you're calling an unbound method via the class, rather than a method on the instance.

It should be:

```
self.cfg = ConfigParser()
```

etc